# PHP retrieve variable from file in OOP

Tags: php, oop

I have a config files which store variable like this:

```
<?php
return array(
    'debug' => true,
    'url' => 'http://localhost',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'en',
);
```

How can I retrieve it in object oriented way from main file? Thank you.

Comment: What does "in object oriented way" mean? There's nothing object oriented about a bunch of keys and values.

Comment: Thanks. But Jayasankar answered my question. That's basically what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am guessing you wanted to convert this array to an object if so then use this.

```
<?php
return (object) array(
    'debug' => true,
    'url' => 'http://localhost',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'locale' => 'en',
);
```

in the other page do this:

```
$config = include("configfile.php");
echo $config->locale;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what sort of answer you're expecting when you say "in an object oriented way", but the way I'd do it would be something like the following:

```
$config = include("configfile.php");
```

And then you can just access the values like so:

```
echo $config["timezone"]; //prints "UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a OOP concept, rather a PHP concept

Simply include the file:

```
$config = include 'config.php';
```